# Use WScript.Shell to redirect output into a new file vba

Tags: vba, command-line

I am trying to redirect output into a file with WScript.Shell in VBA. This is the code block that I am currently using.

```
Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "cmd /c dir > %USERPROFILE%\abc.txt"
Sh.Run cmd, 0, False
```

However, when I check the output folder in %USERPROFILE%, the file is not present. Is there something wrong with the code block that I am using?

When I manually run the following code block in a windows shell, the output file generates as expected.

```
cmd /c dir > %USERPROFILE%\abc.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect output"?

Comment: When manually try, do you open 'cmd' As Administrator?

Comment: Inspect `cmd` before running it.

Comment: Does `\\` have a special meaning in VBA?

Comment: Nope, I'm not running as administrator

Comment: Redirect output as in taking the output of dir command and writing it in a file called abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try, please:

```
cmd = "cmd /c dir > ""%USERPROFILE%\abc.txt"""
```

If you have a problem with above way of building the string, try qualifying the user path using VBA:

```
cmd = "cmd /c dir > """ & Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\bcd.txt"""
```

or even:

```
cmd = "cmd /c dir > """ & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bcd.txt"""
sh.Run cmd, 0, True
sh.Run "notepad """ & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bcd.txt""", 1, True
'it should run the file in Notepad...
```

Both ways work for me...

Comment: Nope, the output file is still not generated

Comment: Just to highlight, when I type cmd /c dir > "%USERPROFILE%\abc.txt" into the command prompt, this works as expected. It only breaks when I use this in VBA.

Comment: @darkvalance : What `Debug.Print Environ("USERPROFILE")` does return in Immediate Window? The above code line string should work in VBA. It works in my case. Maybe the new created file is added of the folder bottom side...

Comment: C:\Users\darkvalance. That's the expected path, strangely, the file is not being generated.

Comment: Maybe the folder is not refreshed... try pressing 'F5'..

Comment: @darkvalance : Still testing? I cannot imagine how it can not work on your environment...

Comment: Yes, I tried everything that you suggested. I'm pretty sure the folder is refreshed, I'm checking the file directly via command line and it's definitely not there when I invoke via WScript in VBA. I suspect either the redirection handled differently in VBA WScript or like you mentioned, there is something wrong with my environment settings.

Comment: @darkvalance : Then, try fully qualifying the user path, since VBA `Environ` returns it correctly. I will edit the code for such a variat...

Comment: @darkvalance :  Didn't the last suggestion work, neither? I cannot believe that...

Comment: I'm using these lines of code exactly

`Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "cmd /c dir > """ & Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\bcd.txt"""
Sh.Run cmd, 0, False`

It's still not working. I don't think there's anything wrong with the cmd variable, it feels like it is related to my environment / excel instead, since running that exact command in the command prompt generates the file as expected. When you run the exact same lines of code in a module / subprocedure from excel, does it generate a file?

Comment: @darkvalance : I did not have the intention to deny that. Still not creating the text file? If yes, I am afraid that it is not a VBA related matter. Try reading the file immediately after it (should be) created.. I will adapt the code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220006/discussion-between-darkvalance-and-faneduru).